# How we can change the general error message: 'You encountered some errors when trying to save this record'

Tags: apex, error-messages

We would like to know if we can change this message when we have an APEX validation problem to something more specific and user friendly.
We add the error message after this title, but can we change it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this message is part of the standard user interface, and further, is translated into all languages that Salesforce supports in case the user changes their language preference.